# How can I determine which numbers of a set total to a given sum.

Tags: integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus

In Excel, I have a list of 30 different numbers ranging from $100$ to $1000$.  If I have a sum representing several of those variable numbers, is there a way for me to determine which possible combinations of those variable numbers total together to equal that sum?

Answer (score 0):

This is called the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which is a type of [knapsack problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) Not very easy to solve. For exact answers we only know exponential algorithms meaning it'll take a while for you to get your answers. If you want faster algorithms then they will only give you approximations.